# Excel: How do I find the second highest value in a range defined by a different column?

Tags: excel-formula

What I would like to get out of Excel is the second highest value in a range that is defined by a "Code" which is given in a different column.

For example: In a table, the values are given in the first column and a code in the second column. For the range of values with code "201" I would like to get the second highest value of that range in the third column.

Value     Code      Second Highest value
20             201          60
30           201          60 
60           201           60 
10           201          60
80           201       60
34           301       21
21           301       21
50           401       50
10           401          50
70           401          50

I tried to use the "Large" function. But when specifying the array, I need to be able to limit that array based on a value in another cell and I'm not sure which formula to use for this.

I hope someone can help me with this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there anything that you tried yourself that you could show? It is often appreciated if you don't just ask the community to solve your problem but show that you made an effort to solve it by yourself before asking here.

Comment: Well, I tried to use the "Large" function. But when specifying the array, I need to be able to limit that array based on a value in another cell and I'm not sure which formula to use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do like this:

```
=LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$11=$B2,$A$2:$A$11,""),2)
```

in this formula:
**$B$2:$B$11** is your *code* column
**$A$2:$A$11** is you *value* column

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula and drag and fill it down until the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell A5 with column A being value and column B being the code.

In cell E5, type in the code your focusing on. In E6, type in the position you'd like. 1 for the highest, 2 for the second highest etc.

Use this formula in F5

```
=LARGE(IF(B5:B14=E5,A5:A14,""),E6)
```

Press control+shift+enter and it'll look like this. This is an array formula

```
={LARGE(IF(B5:B14=E5,A5:A14,""),E6)}
```

It's essentially looking at cells B5 to B14, checking if they equal whatever code is in E5 and then storing the figure from the corresponding cell in column A into an array. The Large part of the formula is then returning the highest depending on what rank you have in E6.

Comment: Thanks! However, this only seems to work for the entire column. What I need to have is basically a second highest value for each different "Code". I have a dataset of more than 50000 rows, so I would like to prevent doing it manually :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, the issue has been resolved by adding the $'s as in the solution above in order to prevent these parts of the formula from changing when dragging it down.